# Calculating First and Follow of a grammar

Tags: parsing, ll-grammar

I'm trying to calculate First and Follow of the following grammar:

```
S -> A B C D E
A -> a
A -> EPSILON
B -> b
B -> EPSILON
C -> c
D -> d
D -> EPSILON
E -> e
E -> EPSILON
```

I calculated them and got `First(S)={a,b,c}`. But using this [tools](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/predict-first-follow-set), says: `First(S)= {a, ε, c, b}`. Why epsilon is part of `First(S)`? As I understand it should not be there. Is it my mistake or a bug? In case it's a bug. Are there other tools I can use to verify my results? In case it's my mistake, it would be helpful to understand why. Printscreen:

[image]

Also I got `Follow(C)={d,e,$}` but their result is `Follow(C)={c, d, $}`. Why?

Comment: It's a bug. The "tool" is unreliable. But it's easy to verify your results using the definitions of FIRST and FOLLOW.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43970429/1566221